# Consume Azure Blob Metadata in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, azure-blob-storage

after opening a blob container in Power BI, all blobs are listed in a table with columns **..., Date modified, Date created, ...** Date modified columns has value, however Date created is empty. I assume this is because the Modified date is taken from the `BlobProperties.LastModified` Property. As there is no property for Date created it must be retrieved from the blob metadata dictionary, which is obviously not set.

In case my assumption is correct, does anybody know the key Power Bi uses to map it to the **Date created** column?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, azure blob (file) only has the property `LastModified`. For Date created, you could use the following approaches:

- Use Metadata. Note: You need to update your blob along with the date created metadata, otherwise metadata would be overwritten when blob is updated.
- Specify the Date created info within the file path of your blob (file).

> In case my assumption is correct, does anybody know the key Power Bi uses to map it to the Date created column?

Click the **Data** tab, then **Get Data > File > Folder**, you could find the file has `Date accessed` and `Date created` as follows:

[image]

Based on my understanding, the azure blob does not has the common properties (Date accessed and Date created), so in the preview table, you could not map the `Date created`.

I assumed that you could format the created date with your blob name, then [Add Column From Examples data transformation](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/a-sneak-preview-of-the-new-add-column-from-examples-data-transformation/) to achieve your purpose. Here is my test, you could refer to it:

**Data Source:**

[image]

**Add custom column for date created:**

[image]

Comment: Bruce, you nicely described my current practice which I want to get rid of :-) it just looks silly that there is a column that nobody can use, and you need to keep the date in the file name. I still do believe, that MS engineers, did map it to a metadata key, and we are just facing a lack of documentation issue, that we do not what key it is. I did try about 20 combinations, without any success